# how to force `tk.messagebox.showerror()` to be active only when particular error occours?

Tags: tkinter, skype

I need to find a way to force Tkinter `messagebox.showerror()` to activate, but only when one type of error occurs - for default, it's activated every time when any type of error occurs. In this case, the problem is even more complex, because I want it to react only on `SkypeAuthException` error, which is related to `SkPy` library, so the error is not related to standard python errors.

I want to create a code where the warning window is displayed only when the wrong password for Skype is provided in GUI. Because my code has exceptions (for various reasons), when I use `messagebox.showerror()`, the window is activated every time when my GUI start to process data.

I've tried to use exceptions with `messagebox.showerror()`, but without success. My code posted below is a part of the definition that is linked to the (trigger)button that allows sending messages to Skype by my GUI. In other words, the button has the command `submit_offers_to_selected_clients`. So, when I press this button, the program is trying to log in to Skype before further action of sending messages. The action of the "sending messages" button needs login and pass to skype.

```
def submit_offers_to_selected_clients():
    
    """
    Because I need a login and a password to access
    the Skype platform before sending messages to clients,
    I need to confirm that these are proper. If they aren't I need to create
    the error message box
    """
    try:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("We can’t sign you!", "Your login or password is not correct. Try to fix it.")

#    except SkypeApiException:
    except SkypeAuthException:     
         tk.messagebox.showerror("We can’t sign you!", "Your login or password is not correct. Try to fix it.")
```

Comment: Why do you call `messagebox.showerror()` in the `try` block? It is why the message box is shown whenever `submit_offers_to_selected_clients()` is executed.

Comment: As I understand, you need to show the error if the user entered wrong credentials, right?

Comment: If yes, can you please share the code which takes the ID and password from the user?
You can add ```if...else``` there. Example: ```print(False) if password != 12345```